# Is it possible to have SKUs automatically generated on publish?

Tags: expresso-store

I have a store implementation where there will only ever be one SKU per inventory item/product. I am interested in having the SKU field equal the title field (using [Title Master](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/title-master-developer-license) so each title is unique).

Has anyone done anything similar?

Cheers,
Sean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Title Master is very useful indeed but I'm not sure you could use that to automatically fill in the SKU with Store however. The reason is that the Store field is itself a compound field so I don't think you'd be able to specify which field within it you'd want to have populated.

As nonprofit_tech mentioned you can either go with a client-side (JS) solution or go server-side (PHP/SQL) but I'd probably look to go with client-side. Either way it will require getting your hands dirty with code to get something working.

For a JS based solution you'd need to use the [cp_js_end](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/extension_hooks/cp/javascript/index.html) hook but you can cut out some of the custom extension work if you use Brandon's handy addon ([CP CSS & JS](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/cp-css-js)) which provides an easy way to add custom JS to the control panel. From there you could use JS or jQuery to grab the contents of the title field, format it, and then insert into the SKU field.

I'd agree with nonprofit_tech though that really you want to keep this short and mimicking the title exactly may not be a good idea as it's open to abuse.

Comment: Thanks Ian, I think that CP CSS & JS add-on will be the go initially. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

SKUs are better smaller. Say 5 to 10 characters, rather than a full title. There may even be a space limit on the field in `Store`, you'd need to check. But if you were going to auto generate one, I'd recommend the `entry_id` over the title. For one client we use, a 3-4 character code for the product section, say: MEM, PUB, etc for Member or Publication, then the entry_id. So final SKU looks like MEM56789 or PUB245.

The problem is that you want to solve the auto-create issue. With `entry_id` you have to grab after the record is created. With title, you could insert or modify the 'as you type' javascript that creates the url_title field and try to auto-fill the SKU field that way. You'd want to check on field limits, maybe remove all spacing. I'm not certain how long your titles generally are. I know our client's can occasionally push the boundaries of the `title` field.

Either way, `entry_id` or `title`, you'd need to create an extension to insert the SKU. You could also do it with a CRON job on a MySQL UPDATE script, as well.

Comment: Interested to know if anyone wrote an extension to automate SKU creation... I have the same issue here... client does not currently has SKUs but wants Store to create them on save.

Answer (score 1):

This might help..., Auto Store SKU, if no SKU value is specified it uses the entry_id to populate the SKU field. You can specify an SKU value and it will leave it as it is.

https://gist.github.com/nathanpitman/9836805